# Gitignore all obj directories except .m and .h files inside them

Tags: git, xamarin, gitignore, xamarin-studio

Xamarin Studio being the piece of junk that it is, I can't just add `obj` to .gitignore because any .h and .m files generated for/by Xcode are stored somewhere in the relevant projects' obj directory. These .h and .m files need to be tracked in the repository, otherwise the build can break for some team members.

How do I ignore a solution's projects' obj directories except any .h and .m files contained therein?

I have tried

```
obj
!*.h
!*.m
```

but the exclusion rules do not work. I've seen `obj/*` recommended in this case, but when I change it to this:

```
obj/*
!*.h
!*.m
```

all obj directories and their contents are tracked.

How do I just ignore everything in all obj directories except .h and .m files?

Answer (score 3):

Your `.gitignore` file explicitly includes `.h` and `.m` files, while you want to include `.h` and `.m` files **inside the `obj` directory**:

```
obj/*
!obj/*.h
!obj/*.m
```

Note you'd still need to `git add obj` in order to track the relevant files inside it.

(Verified with git 1.7.11.3 on RHEL 6.5)

Comment: `obj/*` as a rule does not ignore, for example, anything in `MySolution/MyProject/obj/`, whereas `obj` as a rule does, but then the exclusion rules don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `.gitignore` file proposed here: [gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/)? There is one for XamarinStudio, it may help you to solve your problem.

Hope that this link will help you.

Comment: The generated `.gitignore` for XamarinStudio ignores everything in all `obj` directories, [as you can see here](http://www.gitignore.io/api/xamarinstudio). -1

Comment: Have you tried to put the gitignore for XamarinStudio at the root level and another gitignore file in your Project's root with `!obj/? specified?

Comment: They would just cancel each other out.

Comment: I never used Xamarin Studio, can you provide us the folders structure of your git repo in order to better understand where to put the gitignore file(s)?